# Auto-fill PayPal checkout not working

Tags: paypal, autofill

I'm trying to implement Auto-fill Paypal checkout in my website, but it is not getting the country I provide. It can only get the quantity after submit. Please see the code below:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
   <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Country">
        <label class="control-label">Country</label>
        <select name="os0" class="form-control">
            <option value="US">US</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Quantity">
        <label class="control-label">Quantity</label>
        <select name="os0" class="form-control">
            <option value="11 units">11 units $3,000.00</option>
            <option value="21 units">21 units $6,000.00</option>
            <option value="51 units">51 units $12,500.00</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: name attribute in both country and quantity have same name which might be causing last select to get the value of quantity. Try changing unique name attribute